# apt-get hanging 100% waiting default repos

Tags: apt, aptitude

Apt-get update is hanging at 100%, I've restored my sources.list file to default, yet the problem persists. It's not really a huge issue since it appears to have completed, but it's just cosmetically hung.

uname -a

```
Linux eOS 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here's my apt-get log

```
 Ign hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
    Hit hxxp://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease
    Ign hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
    Hit hxxp://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources
    Ign hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
    Ign hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
    Ign hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
    Hit hxxp://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages
    Ign hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
    Hit hxxp://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release100% [Working] 
    Ign hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Ign hxxp://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
    Ign hxxp://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
    Hit hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
    Ign hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
    Ign hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
    Ign hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
    Ign hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
    100% [Working]
```

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.3 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150411)]/ trusty main restricted

# See hxxp://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src hxxp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb hxxp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src hxxp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb hxxp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src hxxp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb hxxp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src hxxp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb hxxp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src hxxp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb hxxp://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src hxxp://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Why does your sources have hxxp:// not http://? It looks strange but maybe I'm not aware of something obvious.

Comment: I had to replace all the http's with hxxp's because stack exchange wouldn't let me post "links"

Answer (score 1):

I think I resolved this. Apparently the sources.list isn't the only place that contains repositories. I ended up opening the software center and went to edit >software sources.

There was a repo for steam and tox. Once I removed those apt-get behaved normally.

Sorry!